# How to calculate autocorrelation coefficient

Tags: python, julia

Consider `Python` first.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = [0.25, 0.5, 0.2, -0.05]
```

The first way to calculate autocorrelation coefficient of `x`:

```
pd.Series(x).autocorr()
```

The second way:

```
x0 = x[:-1]
x1 = x[1:]
np.corrcoef(x0, x1)[0,1]
```

Both of the above give `0.1035526330902407`.

Now turn to `Julia`. I tried the following

```
using StatsBase
x = [0.25, 0.5, 0.2, -0.05]
autocor(x)[2]
```

which gives `0.04508196721311479`. It is different from what I get from `Python`.

What `Julia` built-in function returns the same value as in `Python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Julia> x = [0.25, 0.5, 0.2, -0.05]

julia> cor(x[1:3],x[2:4])
0.10355263309024072
```

and in general `pd.Series(x).autocorr(lag=t)` is equivalent to `cor(x[1:end-t],x[1+t:end])`

ADDENDUM: So why are the results different. What is going on?

On the Python side, the autocorrelation is simply the covariance between shifted windows onto the vector `x` i.e. `cov(x[1:end-t],x[1+t:end])` as mentioned earlier.

On the Julia side, the autocorrelation is obtained by de-meaning `x` (subtracting the mean, not insulting the vector). Calling the result `y`, a normalizing factor is calculated with `dot(y,y)` (which also gives the variance of `x`). For each lag `t`, `dot(y[1:end-t], y[1+t:end])` is divided by the normalizing factor and the result returned. So for the example in the OP, the calculation is `y = x .- mean(x); dot(y[1:3],y[2:4])/dot(y,y)`.